# Changing the background color of text in VS Code themes

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

With SublimeText you can do something like this (look at the blue background for the tags). I looked up but it looks like Visual Studio Code still doesn't support this feature. Can anyone confirm this?

[image]

Comment: if these tags have a specific `TextMate Scope` you can customize the front/back color

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it really seems impossible :(
https://www.mirari.fr/QmNS.png

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3429

Comment: then you can use the extension `Highlight`